# Why is getAttribute not defined?

Tags: javascript, properties

I have this script that I'm running.  It's showing that getAttribute property is undefined on line 164.  I don't understand why.  I've tried backtracking the various function calls to look for the break, but I don't see it

[Look for Album.js file](https://github.com/jar9tf/bloc-jams/tree/scratch.js)

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(songItem)` between line 163 and 164 and tell me if you have an error displayed

Comment: @Ivan Seconded. The most logical explanation is that `songItem` is `undefined` or of the wrong type, like `false`.

Comment: Does the control you are looking this attribute in contains the attribute.  Check in html source.

Comment: It seems `getSongItem()` doesn't always return a value, look line 77. So my bet is `songItem` is not defined

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself. **Do not just post a link to code**. We're trying to build a repository of questions that will help more than one person. When that link goes down, this question will become meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mouseleave` event listener is always going to have the `event.target.className` of `album-view-song-item` because `songRows` is defined as `document.getElementsByClassName("album-view-song-item");`

Therefore, when the `getSongItem(event.target)` is called within the listener:

```
songRows[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
    var songItem = getSongItem(event.target);
    var songItemNumber = songItem.getAttribute("data-song-number");

    if (songItemNumber !== currentlyPlayingSong){
        songItem.innerHTML = songItemNumber;
    }
});
```

The `element.className` is `album-view-song-item`.  When this is passed into your function:

```
var getSongItem = function(element){
    switch(element.className){
        case "album-song-button":
        case "ion-play":
        case "ion-pause":
            return findParentByClassName(element, "song-item-number");
        case "song-item-title":
        case "song-item-duration":
            return findParentByClassName(element, "album-view-song-item").querySelector(".song-item-number");
        case "song-item-number": 
            return  element;
        default:
            return;
    }
};
```

This falls through to the `default` case, which returns undefined. Calling `getAttribute` on undefined, as you may see, gives you the error `Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined`